# How to split a xml file using shell script based on a tag value

Tags: shell

I am having a below sample XML file as source.

```
<XML version?>
<DATA>
<List>
    <A> </A>
    <B>100</B>
    <C> </C>
</List>
<List>
    <A> </A>
    <B>200</B>
    <C> </C>
</List>
<List>
    <A> </A>
    <B>100</B>
    <C> </C>
</List>
<List>
    <A> </A>
    <B>100</B>
    <C> </C>
</List>
</DATA>
```

Based on the value in tag B, I need to create a new xml file.

For eg, I have to filter values other than 100 in tag B and I need to create a new xml file as shown below,

```
<XML version?>
<DATA>
<List>
    <A> </A>
    <B>100</B>
    <C> </C>
</List>
<List>
    <A> </A>
    <B>100</B>
    <C> </C>
</List>
<List>
    <A> </A>
    <B>100</B>
    <C> </C>
</List>
</DATA>
```

Please let me know, how to do it in shell scripting. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using it as a filter from `stdin` to `stdout`:

```
    sed -ne'/<List>/!{p;b};:a;H;/<\/List>/!{n;ba};x;/<B>100<\/B>/p'
```

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/do_it_with_sed.txt) for details.

Comment: Would fail with the exact same document with namespace aliases in place; with attributes added (ie. `<List foo="bar">` failing to match `<List>`, or `<B bar="baz">` failing to match `<B>`), or with whitespace (`<List >` is completely valid XML), or with newlines removed, or with any number of other formatting changes that don't impact the document's semantic correctness.

Comment: I am able to split using the sed command. But each time, i am getting </List> twice in my output xml for all the <List>. Please let me know how to avoid one </List>.

Comment: Moreover I am having an additional requirement to have one more <B>value(say it as 300). Is there a way to redesign the same script to get both 100 and 300 values into a single XML?

Thanks for your time @Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool that's actually XML-aware. For instance, with [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html):

```
# delete all List elements with a B having a value other than 100
xmlstarlet ed -d '//List[B != "100"]' <in.xml >out.xml
```

To iterate over all such values might look like the following:

```
infile=in.xml

# to output to out-<B_VALUE>.xml
out_prefix=out-
out_suffix=.xml

while read -r b_value; do
  xmlstarlet ed -d "//List[B != '${b_value}']" \
    <"$infile" \
    >"${out_prefix}${b_value}${out_suffix}"
done < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//List/B' -v . -n <"$infile" | sort -u)
```

---

After fixing your input file to actually be valid XML (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`, not `<XML version?>`), I get the two files created from your sample input.

`out-100.xml` contains the following:

```
<DATA>
  <List>
    <A> </A>
    <B>100</B>
    <C> </C>
  </List>
  <List>
    <A> </A>
    <B>100</B>
    <C> </C>
  </List>
  <List>
    <A> </A>
    <B>100</B>
    <C> </C>
  </List>
</DATA>
```

...and `out-200.xml` thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA>
  <List>
    <A> </A>
    <B>200</B>
    <C> </C>
  </List>
</DATA>
```